# Cordova android gradle error when building

Tags: maven, cordova, gradle, phonegap

I had android building working for Cordova working for a while, then I tried to upgrade the cordova android version and now after having spent a whole day on it I can't get it to work again.

First it wouldn't download gradle, but I found a solution for that where I could get it to download from localhost.

Now it won't download gradle-2.2.3.pom from either maven or jcenter. The URL's it complains about all work in the browser, but it fails instantly in the console, clearly not even trying. The thing is the first time I got it to work I was in China, so I used some proxy settings I think to get it to work (since they block everything). I have unset all the proxy settings I could think of and even reinstalled, cordova, node+npm, cordova android and even Android Studio, but I cannot for the life of me get it to work.

This is the actual error I get from the console:

> A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
>   Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
>   Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3.
>        Required by:
>            project :
>   Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3.
>   Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.3/gradle-2.2.3.pom'.
>   Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.3/gradle-2.2.3.pom'.
>   Connect to jcenter.bintray.com:443 [jcenter.bintray.com/127.0.1.3] failed: Connection refused: connect
>   Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3.
>   Could not get resource 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.3/gradle-2.2.3.pom'.
>   Could not GET 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.3/gradle-2.2.3.pom'.
>   Connect to repo1.maven.org:443 [repo1.maven.org/127.0.1.2] failed: Connection refused: connect

Any ideas very much appreciated! I'm on Windows 10 and since I reinstalled everything today I'm now on cordova 7.01 and Android studio 2.3.3 (although it also didn't work with the earlier versions).

Comment: Same here. Looks like it's broken and Android Studio 2.2.3 disappeared from the internet completely

Comment: Worked for me after installing Oracle JDK instead of open one  
https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/1782